# SymmetricAlgorithm DES C#. Base64

Tags: c#, encryption, msdn, des

So im trying to encrypt data using C# DES

have the following code

```
            static public string Encrypt(string _dataToEncrypt) {
                SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = DES.Create();
                ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
                byte[] inputbuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_dataToEncrypt);
                byte[] outputBuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputbuffer, 0, inputbuffer.Length);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBuffer);
            }

            static public string Decrypt(string _dataToDecrypt) {
                SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = DES.Create();
                ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
                byte[] inputbuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(_dataToDecrypt); // Here is the problem.
                byte[] outputBuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputbuffer, 0, inputbuffer.Length);
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outputBuffer);
            }
```

And im getting an error `System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.'`

It works when string has an even number of characters.

Is it even real to encrypt/decrypt data with an odd number of characters ?

Comment: Do not use DES in new code, it is insecure and has be superceeded by AES.

Comment: Provide sample input/output that demonstrates the error including `_dataToDecrypt` in. Is

Answer (score 1):

DES, as well as AES does not have limit on what can be encrypted, the problem is elsewhere.

It looks like it is a Bas64 encoding problem given the line the error occurs on.

Perhaps trailing "=" characters were stripped from the Base64.

Information:

DES is a block based encryption algorithm, as such the input must be an exact multiple of the block size, 8-bytes for DES. When the input is not *always* an exact multiple padding must be added, the easiest way to to let the implementation do that for you by specifying padding, generally PKCS#5 for DES.

For SymmetricAlgorithm use Padding Property `PKCS7`, it is always best to fully specify everything and not rely on defaults.

```
algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
```